# org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient listFiles always returns files from root directory irrespective of the pathname given in argument

Tags: java, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

listFiles in the class FTPClient is always returning the directories or files from the root directory, even when the path is given as argument.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String server = "192.168.0.60";
    int port = 21;
    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {

        ftpClient.connect(server,port);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftpClient.login("anonymous", "");
        FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles("/StorageCard");
        for(FTPFile ftpFile: files) {
            System.out.println(ftpFile.getName());
        }
    } catch(IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

StorageCard is a directory inside the rootfolder

Output what I get is

1. Network Internal Storage
2. WinDrive
3. **StorageCard**
4. Application Data
5. My Documents
6. Program Files
7. Windows
8. .........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be changing working directory before using `listFiles()`

```
ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("StorageCard");
FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles();
```